# PHP Regex Negative Assertions explanation

Tags: php, regex-negation

I tried to understand the php manual
[PCRE regex syntax->Assertions](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php)

There is one description as follow:

`foo(?!bar) matches any occurrence of "foo" that is NOT followed by "bar".`

While I have tried the sample with the following result:

```
$text = "foobar foobar foobar fooabar";
$rules = "/foo(!?bar)/is";
preg_match_all($rules, $text, $matches);
$newLine = preg_replace($rules, "\thahaha", $text);
print_r( $matches );
echo "<br/>";
echo $rules. ":" .$newLine;

// result
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => foobar [1] => foobar [2] => foobar ) [1] =>     Array ( [0] => bar [1] => bar [2] => bar ) ) 
/foo(!?bar)/is: hahaha hahaha hahaha fooabar
```

All occurrence of "foo" with "bar" is replaced.
So, is it actually the opposite meaning? Or did I missing something elsewhere?

`foo(?!bar) matches any occurrence of "foo" that is followed by "bar"???`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It should be `foo(?!bar)` and not `foo(!?bar)`.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, I should take more careful look in details next time. :) @Rahul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex is `foo(!?bar)` which will check for `foo` then an **optional** `!` then `bar`, which is found in first three strings. `foobar foobar foobar`

You have misplaced `!` and `?`.

Correct regex should be `foo(?!bar)` which will match last string `fooabar`

Answer (score 2):

? denotes an optional expression. In your example it means that ! can be there or not. Which means that you are matching `bar` or `!bar`.

A negative lookahead is the other way around. `(?!bar)` remember that the question mark always goes after the parenthetical opening

Comment: Thanks for your time to explain, I just choose the first one to be the answer and upvote you as well. @fleshTH